# How to make a timeseries boxplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a time series boxplot using `ggplot2`.

I have montly values for many individuals.

I need to make a timeseries boxplot by month with my data.

I think that my problem is how to create a factor (month) with my data.

```
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(factor(date), measure))
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, boxplots use a categorical data as the x axis. Effectively this would turn the date into a label rather than a date, stripping the information there away. I'm not sure that there is way to properly plot time on the x axis so that the spacing (cadence?) of the time is preserved.

Comment: To make something like this:

![http://i.imgur.com/bM6Lyje.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated:** Based on OP's clarification that multiple years have to be handled separately.

```
library(ggplot2)

#generate dummy data
date_range <- as.Date("2010/06/01") + 0:400
measure <- runif(401)
mydata <- data.frame(date_range, measure)

# create new columns for the months and years, and 
# and a year_month column for x-axis labels
mydata$month <- format(date_range, format="%b")
mydata$year <- as.POSIXlt(date_range)$year + 1900
mydata$year_month <- paste(mydata$year, mydata$month)
mydata$sort_order <- mydata$year *100 + as.POSIXlt(date_range)$mon

#plot it
ggplot(mydata) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=reorder(year_month, sort_order), y=measure))
```

Which produces:
[image]

Hope this helps you move forward.

Comment: Thanks Ram, it worked.
However, it's is grouping all different years in the same months.
My data range from 2010 to 2011, so I need 2 "jan, feb, mar...".
Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my answer so that each "Year-Month" is plotted individually and not grouped.

Answer (score 14):

Another way to do this without having to change to date format and do any sorting etc. is to simply add the date as a grouping factor like so:

`ggplot(mydata) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = date, y = measure, group = date))`

Answer (score 3):

I create a function to create the plot you need.

the function is:

```
ts_plot_season <- function(x = x) {
season <- cycle(x)
season.factor <- factor(season)
ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x = season.factor,
                             y = x)) +
  labs(x = "Periodo", y =  "Serie")
}
```

Fox example:

```
 ts_plot_season(AirPassengers)
```

[image: Boxplot for time series]

I hope this help. I know this question is old, but i couldn't find some god answer on the web. So i think this will help to someone.