# Boxplot by Date in R

Tags: r, xts, boxplot, zoo

I have data collected daily over time. I would like to plot the data as a boxplot that summarizes DAILY data. Most of the examples that I have seen have data collected on a [daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389553/how-to-make-a-timeseries-boxplot-in-r) or monthly basis, and make boxplots out of those.

As an example:

```
    library(xts)
 dates=c(rep("2011-02-11",8),rep("2011-02-13",8),rep("2011-02-19",8))
measure=rnorm(length(dates))
example <- as.xts( measure,order.by = as.Date( dates ))
boxplot(coredata(example), order.by=index(example),.CLASS = "xts")
```

I end up with no separation by date.

I cannot figure this out. I think it might have something to do with how R handles X values, I heard that it turns them into factors. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: `coredata()` removes all the date information. That is what is stored in the `index` of zoo/xts objects.

Comment: This is true, however if I simple ask for `boxplot(example)` it gives me the error `Error in try.xts(c(1.03773548252495e-317, 2.06236439159703e-317, 7.76223611312559e-316,  : 
  Error in xts(coredata(x), order.by = index(x), .CLASS = "xts", ...) :   order.by requires an appropriate time-based object`, which can be temporarily fixed by asking `boxplot(coredata(example) ~ index(example))`, but this leaves me with evenly spaced boxplots, while the dates are uneven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution using data.frame instead of as.xts:

```
example <- data.frame(dates=as.Date(dates),measure=measure)
boxplot(example$measure ~ example$dates)
```

[image]

**Update**

A way to create spaces for missing dates is to make a new dataset that contains NA's for all missing dates, and then allow for NA's in the boxplot.

Original example

```
dates=c(rep("2011-02-11",8),rep("2011-02-13",8),rep("2011-02-19",8))
measure=rnorm(length(dates))
example <- data.frame(dates=as.Date(dates),measure=measure)
```

Create a template data.frame, with start date and en date

```
n=20
template<-data.frame(dates = seq(as.Date(c("2011-02-11")), by = 'day', length = n))
```

Merge the template and example sothat the missing dates have value NA for your variable "measure", and finally boxplot.

```
df<-merge(template, example, all.x=TRUE, by="dates")

boxplot(df$measure ~ addNA(df$dates))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That solves one of my issues. I was hoping to solve it using xts so that it could handle unevenly spaced dates.

Comment: great to have helped you! Could you give an example with which unevenly spaced dates the data.frame solution would have a problem?

Comment: In the current example, the dates are set at February 11th, 13th, and 19th. While these dates are separated by 2 and 6 days, they appear evenly spaced on the plot.

Comment: I have made an update to add space for missing dates, the trick is to use the NA function in boxplot and adept the input data set. Hope it works!

Comment: WOW! thank you Ruthger that is amazing! I don't think I have seen the addNA() function, very cool. This is perfect thank you very much!