# ggplot + boxplot with time series value by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

A variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389553/how-to-make-a-timeseries-boxplot-in-r) -- I can't quite get the dimensions right in the data structure to make a boxplot with the right values.

what I'm looking to do: hours would be on the x-axis, region would be on the y-axis, and for every region there will be a boxplot showing the distribution of income by hour.

The closest I can get is the following, but it's not right. How do I create the boxplot with two factors (one a time series) as axes, populated by the value distribution?

data:

```
regions <- structure(list(location = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("east", 
"north", "west"), class = "factor"), hour = structure(list(sec = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L), mday = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), mon = c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L
), year = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
115L, 115L), wday = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), yday = c(224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 
224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 
224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 
224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 224L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    zone = c("CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", 
    "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", 
    "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", 
    "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT"), 
    gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
"zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), hour_income = c(67L, 
98L, 89L, 75L, 75L, 89L, 70L, 97L, 52L, 94L, 80L, 84L, 52L, 82L, 
81L, 93L, 85L, 94L, 64L, 90L, 54L, 60L, 97L, 100L, 57L, 63L, 
90L, 58L, 86L, 68L, 52L, 78L, 61L)), .Names = c("location", "hour", 
"hour_income"), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the boxplot

```
ggplot(regions) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=hour, y=hour_income, group=location))
```

Answer (score 0):

First we convert datetimes to character format, then create the boxplots.

```
regions$hour <- strftime(regions$hour, format="%H:%M:%S")
ggplot(data = regions, aes(x = hour, y = hour_income)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

But because you only have an observation for each region and hour when you try to create a boxplot to visualise the regions you can only obtain lines instead of boxplots, which are not very meaningful:

```
ggplot(data = regions, aes(x = hour, y = hour_income)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill= location))
```

[image]