# How can I generate a series boxplot per hour of day for this dataset?

Tags: r, boxplot

Given the sample data below, I'd like to generate a series of boxplots, one per hour showing the distribution of the "usage" column.
I've been fighting with this problem for far too long, and I just can't figure out the right syntax to get my datetime variable into a proper form that it can be used as a grouping for the boxplot.  I've tried a few different ways of getting it into a POSIXct or POSIXlt, but even after doing that, I can't figure out how to break it down into hour groups.

I would greatly appreciate your assistance here.

```
df <- read.table(text="datetime,usage,available
2016-05-25 10:00:59.000000,12,96
             2016-05-25 09:00:59.000000,8,96
             2016-05-25 08:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-25 07:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-25 06:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-25 05:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-25 04:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-25 03:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-25 02:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-25 01:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-25 00:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-24 23:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-24 22:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-24 21:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-24 20:00:59.000000,2,96
             2016-05-24 19:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-24 18:00:59.000000,8,96
             2016-05-24 17:00:59.000000,15,96
             2016-05-24 16:00:59.000000,20,96
             2016-05-24 15:00:59.000000,19,96
             2016-05-24 14:00:59.000000,3,96
             2016-05-24 13:00:59.000000,6,96
             2016-05-24 12:00:59.000000,9,96
             2016-05-24 11:00:59.000000,13,96
             2016-05-24 10:00:59.000000,16,96
             2016-05-24 09:00:59.000000,11,96
             2016-05-24 08:00:59.000000,1,96
             2016-05-24 07:00:59.000000,5,96
             2016-05-24 06:00:59.000000,2,96
             2016-05-24 05:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-24 04:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-24 03:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-24 02:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-24 01:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-24 00:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-23 23:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-23 22:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-23 21:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-23 20:00:59.000000,4,96
             2016-05-23 19:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-23 18:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-23 17:00:59.000000,0,96
             2016-05-23 16:00:59.000000,3,96
             2016-05-23 15:00:59.000000,5,96
             2016-05-23 14:00:59.000000,2,96
             2016-05-23 13:00:59.000000,18,96
             2016-05-23 12:00:59.000000,10,96
             2016-05-23 11:00:59.000000,7,96
             2016-05-23 10:00:59.000000,9,96
             2016-05-23 09:00:59.000000,1,96
             2016-05-23 08:00:59.000000,1,96
             2016-05-23 07:00:59.000000,1,96
             2016-05-23 06:00:59.000000,1,96
             2016-05-23 05:00:59.000000,1,96
             2016-05-23 04:00:59.000000,1,96
             2016-05-23 03:00:59.000000,1,96
             2016-05-23 02:00:59.000000,1,96
             2016-05-23 01:00:59.000000,1,96
             2016-05-23 00:00:59.000000,1,96", sep=",", header=T)
```

Comment: I would convert the hours to minutes and keep only the first two columns , look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389553/how-to-make-a-timeseries-boxplot-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example

```
df <- read.table(sep=",", header=T, text="
datetime,usage,available
2016-05-25 10:00:59.000000,12,96
2016-05-25 09:00:59.000000,8,96
2016-05-25 08:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-25 07:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-25 06:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-25 05:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-25 04:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-25 03:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-25 02:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-25 01:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-25 00:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-24 23:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-24 22:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-24 21:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-24 20:00:59.000000,2,96
2016-05-24 19:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-24 18:00:59.000000,8,96
2016-05-24 17:00:59.000000,15,96
2016-05-24 16:00:59.000000,20,96
2016-05-24 15:00:59.000000,19,96
2016-05-24 14:00:59.000000,3,96
2016-05-24 13:00:59.000000,6,96
2016-05-24 12:00:59.000000,9,96
2016-05-24 11:00:59.000000,13,96
2016-05-24 10:00:59.000000,16,96
2016-05-24 09:00:59.000000,11,96
2016-05-24 08:00:59.000000,1,96
2016-05-24 07:00:59.000000,5,96
2016-05-24 06:00:59.000000,2,96
2016-05-24 05:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-24 04:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-24 03:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-24 02:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-24 01:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-24 00:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-23 23:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-23 22:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-23 21:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-23 20:00:59.000000,4,96
2016-05-23 19:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-23 18:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-23 17:00:59.000000,0,96
2016-05-23 16:00:59.000000,3,96
2016-05-23 15:00:59.000000,5,96
2016-05-23 14:00:59.000000,2,96
2016-05-23 13:00:59.000000,18,96
2016-05-23 12:00:59.000000,10,96
2016-05-23 11:00:59.000000,7,96
2016-05-23 10:00:59.000000,9,96
2016-05-23 09:00:59.000000,1,96
2016-05-23 08:00:59.000000,1,96
2016-05-23 07:00:59.000000,1,96
2016-05-23 06:00:59.000000,1,96
2016-05-23 05:00:59.000000,1,96
2016-05-23 04:00:59.000000,1,96
2016-05-23 03:00:59.000000,1,96
2016-05-23 02:00:59.000000,1,96
2016-05-23 01:00:59.000000,1,96
2016-05-23 00:00:59.000000,1,96")
boxplot(df$usage~as.POSIXlt(df$datetime)$hour)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but due to the errors, I thought I was taking the wrong approach.  

Here is the output I'm seeing:


`Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 

  'x' must be atomic

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In is.na(x) :

  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'

2: In is.na(x) :

  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'`

Comment: What's the output of `str(df[,c("datetime", "usage")])`?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't follow-up on this.  Since you demonstrated a solution that appears to work, I marked it answered.