# Separate boxes for two grouping variables when color by only one variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Here is an example from the [`geom_boxplot` man page](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html):

```
p = ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(colour = drv))
```

which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to make a very similar plot, but with (`yearmon` formatted) dates where the `class` variable is in the example, and a factor variable where `drv` is in the example.

Here is some sample data:

```
df_box = data_frame(
  Date = sample(
    as.yearmon(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2013-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-08-01"), by = "month")),
    size = 10000, 
    replace = TRUE
  ),
  Source = sample(c("Inside", "Outside"), size = 10000, replace = TRUE),
  Value = rnorm(10000)
)
```

I have tried a bunch of different things:

1. Put an `as.factor` around the date variable, then I no longer have the nicely spaced out date scale for the x-axis:

   ```
       df_box %>% 
         ggplot(aes(
         x = as.factor(Date),
       y = Value,
       # group = Date, 
       color = Source
     )) + 
     geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
     theme_bw() + 
     xlab("Month Year") + 
     theme(
       axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, angle = 50)
     )
   ```

[image]

2. On the other hand, if I use `Date` as an additional `group` variable as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27792544/1414455), adding `color` no longer has any additional impact:

   ```
       df_box %>% 
         ggplot(aes(
           x = Date,
           y = Value,
           group = Date, 
           color = Source
         )) + 
        geom_boxplot() + 
        theme_bw()
   ```

[image]

Any ideas as to how achieve the output of #1 while still maintaining a `yearmon` scale x-axis?

Comment: You could use facetting instead of color, e.g. `ggplot(df_box, aes(x = Date, y = Value, group = factor(Date))) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~Source)`

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for that suggestion. I did try it, but it is easiest to compare distributions when they are side by side, especially when there are as many components as there are in a boxplot to compare.

Comment: You can facet vertically with `facet_grid`, if you like. I figured out how to do it as you had it, though, by using an interaction of `Source` and `Date` as the `group` aesthetic: `ggplot(df_box, aes(x = Date, y = Value, colour = Source, group = interaction(Source, Date))) + geom_boxplot()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you need separate boxes for each combination of `Date` and `Source`, use `interaction(Source, Date)` as the `group` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(df_box, aes(x = Date, y = Value, 
                   colour = Source, 
                   group = interaction(Source, Date))) + 
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image: plot with date formatted x-axis]