# Fill boxplot by variable but keep date scale GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe containing values for three variables at three different dates:

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c(rep('2021-01-01',6),rep('2021-05-04',6),rep('2015-04-04',6))),
             variable = rep(c('apple','bananna','carrot'),6),
             value = rnorm(18,5,2))
```

I'd like to make a boxplot with fill relating to variable, date on the x axis and value on the y axis:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=as.factor(date),y=value,fill=variable))+geom_boxplot()
```

This fills based on variable, but it doesn't scale date according to the actual differences in time:
[image]

If I set `group=date`, it gets scaled properly, but `fill=variable` stops working:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=date,y=value,group=date,fill=variable))+geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

How do I get the date to scale properly and also fill based on variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved with the creation of a factor variable combining `date` and `variable`. This is done with `interaction`.

I have also added code to increase the plot window width, in order to make the bars and labels more visible.

```r
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c(rep('2021-01-01',6),rep('2021-05-04',6),rep('2015-04-04',6))),
                 variable = rep(c('apple','bananna','carrot'),6),
                 value = rnorm(18,5,2))

library(ggplot2)

x11(width = 20, height = 8)    # this is not stricktly needed

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = interaction(date, variable))) +
  scale_x_date(
    breaks = unique(df$date),
    date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d"
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

The same can be done by creating a temporary new factor in a `dplyr` pipe to `mutate`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
})

df %>%
  mutate(group = interaction(date, variable)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = group)) +
  scale_x_date(
    breaks = unique(df$date),
    date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d"
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809001/separate-boxes-for-two-grouping-variables-when-color-by-only-one-variable). You need to create an interaction for the group: `group=interaction(variable,date)`:

```
   ggplot(df,aes(x=date,y=value,group=interaction(variable,date),fill=variable))+geom_boxplot()
```

[image]